# Distinction of force carrying particles unnecessary?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model

In QFT, diagrammatically we just loosely say that exchange of virtual particles basically causes a force between two particles like two electrons, but in many interactions these virtual particles can be what we call matter particles as well, in a sense shouldn't this distinction of force carrying particles of photons, W or Z bosons, gluons and gravitons be unnecessary? Any particle can mediate interactions depending on the type of process and vertices we have. So, we basically just have particles and their interactions. Disclaimer: This was not my original thought, Prof. Susskind had suggested this in one of lectures (New Revolutions in Physics, standard model). I am just wondering if there are counter arguments to this idea.

Comment: Well, one issue is that you can't "exchange" a fermion without changing the identities of the particles that are interacting. When a particle absorbs (or emits) a fermion, its spin has to change between integer and half-integer.

Comment: Force carrying particles can also change identities. I don't know if that's a definitive feature of force carrying particle. Except that they are all coming from some kind of gauge freedom.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose the distinction isn’t very sharp. When people say “force carrier” they just mean “gauge boson” but it’s mostly historical convention.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of agree but with many questions that haven't quite taken shape yet. In my mind, I have no issues defining massless particles (before SSB) as irreps of Poincare group but how we use non-covariant potentials and then use gauge freedom to actually describe these particles using local fields is sometimes uncomfortable. And they do have many distinct properties.